# How to do conditional merge

Tags: r, join, inner-join

I have 2 data frames, and I'm trying to do an inner join using a condition. I'll show an example to clarify what I'm trying to do:

```
A
  cnumero cep numero bairro
1  124,35 124     35      K
2  375,NA 375     NA      L
3   NA,28  NA     28      M

B

  cnumero bairro XY
1  124,35      J  1
2  375,48      L  2
3  135,28      M  3
```

The first condition to merge is, if `A$cep != NA` and `A$numero != NA`, then the join is made using the column `cnumero`, otherwise the join is made using the column `bairro`, resulting in:

```
new_A
  cnumero cep numero XY
1  124,35 124     35  1
2  375,NA 375     NA  2
3   NA,28  NA     28  3
```

What I have done so far is to make the inner join using this:
`A[A$cnumero %in% unique(B$cnumero),]`, since in my real dataframe I have repeated values in data frame `B`.

Edit: my data example

```
A = data.frame(cnumero=c("124,35", "375,NA", "NA,28"),cep = c(124, 375, NA), numero = c(35, NA, 28), bairro =  c("K", "L","M"))
B = data.frame(cnumero=c("124,35", "375,48", "135,28"), bairro =  c("J", "L","M"), XY = c(1, 2, 3))
new_A = data.frame(cnumero=c("124,35", "375,NA", "NA,28"),cep = c(124, 375, NA), numero = c(35, NA, 28), XY = c(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: Are you sure that A is ok? There is no `NA` in `A$cnumero` (look at `is.na(A$cnumero)`) so your result cannot be achieved to me. Do you mean that it should be the string "NA" `A$cnumero`?

Comment: `A$numero` and  `A$cep` are numeric, but `A$cnumero` is string.

Comment: It is indeed an NA, but if you import the data using `read.table` it becomes an "NA". Would be easier if @Ga13 would share the data with `dput`. Or add `na.strings = "NA"` when using `read.table`

Comment: Wouldnt it be easier to merge two times?

Comment: @desval am I missing the point? `A <- read.table(text ="
cnumero cep numero bairro
1  124,35 124     35      K
2  375,NA 375     NA      L
3   NA,28  NA     28      M", header = T,na.strings = "NA");

is.na(A$cnumero) # FALSE FALSE FALSE`, same with the data given by OP.

Comment: sorry, got confused, the point was that there need to be no `NA` in `cnumero`. The relevant columns are the other two, and `NA` are recognized correctly by default

Comment: @desval no problem, I've genuinely thought I was missing something (also, it arises a question: how it's possible to mark as NA both columns?). I've thought the same, but OP specified that it's necessary `cnumero`, so I've given my solution with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a solution in base R in this way, doing two steps, first the join for the first condition, then for the second, last put results together:

```
# the join with the first condition
A_1 <-  merge(A[!is.na(A$cep) & !grepl('NA',A$cnumero), ],B, by = 'cnumero')

# select the column you need
A_1 <- A_1[,c("cnumero", "cep","numero","XY")]

# join for the second condition
A_2 <-  merge(A[is.na(A$cep) | grepl('NA',A$cnumero), ],B, by = 'bairro')

# select columns you need
A_2 <- A_2[,c("cnumero.x", "cep","numero","XY")]

# rename the second part's columns
colnames(A_2) <- colnames(A_1)

# now the result 
new_A <- rbind(A_1,A_2)
new_A
  cnumero cep numero XY
1  124,35 124     35  1
2  375,NA 375     NA  2
3   NA,28  NA     28  3

# in case you need to remove the "temporary" tables
# remove(A_1, A_2)
```